# Can I close file handles opened by code I don't own?

Tags: java, io

I'm using a third-party commercial library which seems to be leaking file handles (I verified this on Linux using `lsof`).  Eventually the server (Tomcat) starts getting the infamous "Too many open files error", and I have to re-start the JVM.

I've already contacted the vendor.  In the meantime, however, I would like to find a workaround for this.  I do **not** have access to their source code.  Is there any way, in Java, to clean up file handles **without** having access to the original `File` object (or `FileWriter`, `FileOutputStream`, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

a fun way would be to write a dynamic library and use LD_PRELOAD to load it for the java instance you are launching ... this DLL could override the appropriate underlying open(2) system call (or use some other logic) to close existing file descriptors of the process before passing the call to the libc implementation (or the kernel). You need to do some serious accounting and possibly deal with threads; but it can be done. Especially if you take hints from /proc/pid/fd/ for figuring whether or not a close is appropriate for the target fd.

Comment: You don't need to write your own preload library to do syscall interception on Linux.  Just run tomcat under [`systrace`](http://www.provos.org/index.php?/categories/2-Systrace).

Comment: @MikeSamuel errr. systrace is a kernel patch (and a really terrible one at that) + a whole bunch of policy writing; and is overkill for this particular job.  A shared object can be developed in a couple of hours that does this from scratch; is well managed and can be easily turned off without rebooting someone's production system.

Comment: Wow!  That sounds like quite a project :-).  I'm not sure I have the skills for this, but +1 for a creative answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could, on startup, open a bunch of files and use [`File*putStream.getFD()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#getFD%28%29) to obtain a bunch of [`java.io.FileDescriptor`s](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html), then close them, but hold onto the descriptors.  Later you *might* be able to [create streams](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream%28java.io.FileDescriptor%29) using those stored `FileDescriptor`s and close them.

I have not tested this, so would not be surprised if it did not work on some platforms.

Comment: @AhmedMasud, he doesn't need it if old file descriptors allow forging of streams.  All he needs is the ability to run Java code inside a tomcat instance he controls.

Comment: interesting concept but that's assuming that the file descriptors use sane recycling after close; also it may be difficult to figure out WHEN to create streams within the thread;

Comment: @AhmedMasud, Yep.  I haven't tested it so yes, the first problem is open.  The second problem will be present with any solution -- if a black box doesn't release FDs then you have a problem of figuring out when to close FDs.

Comment: @MikeSamuel does this require that I know the file names ahead of time?  Unfortunately, they are randomly generated.

Comment: Although they do follow a specific pattern (e.g. "Acme*.tmp"), so I could discover the file names after they have already been created by the third-party library.

Comment: @MattSolnit.  No it does not require you to know file names.  Open files are associated with a file descriptor.  If this scheme works, it would allow you to have a reference to a `FileDescriptor` even when you don't have a reference to the `FileInputStream` or `FileOutputStream`.